# design pattern for participant list presence query in group chat

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I am working on group chat application on android.

Currently i show the participant list on tap of button on group chat screen.
I need to show offline/online status of each participant in participant list.

**Currently i get the offline/online status by creating a thread for each participant and asking the service about its status.**

So there are n number of threads running for n number of participants.

I want to change this design/optimize this code and introduce some sort of manager in between or whatever.

With current approach, power consumption is high for phone, i need to somehow lower the power consumption i.e. optimize the code.

Which design pattern or technique i should use to optimize this problem?

Code is like

```
    while(all contacts)
    {
       AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       //error handling
                       checkPresenceByContactId(contactId);
                       //error handling
                    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think using the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to monitor the event you are interested at and notify appropriately a list of observers when changes occur so they may respond accordningly.